# Textarea.value doesn't manipulate the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Setting the value of the textarea, won't be reflected in the HTML.

For instance,

If you have `<textarea></textarea>` in your HTML, and set its value to 'Hello' the HTML will remain unchanged and not `<textarea>Hello</textarea>`

Comment: did you tried adding html in the textarea and then hit try it

Comment: `How do I solve this?` Could you explain more, what you want solving.  It's a little unclear what your asking.

Comment: I think I need some English to English translation software, Jacob & Chase seem to know what the OP wants, but my brain is stuck in an infinite loop.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, use this to your w3schools example

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

myTextarea.onkeyup=()=>myTextarea.innerText=myTextarea.value;

</script>
```

Comment: What is this meant to do exactly?

Comment: he wants when he inspects the element the actual text inside <textarea> block change when he types

Comment: you might be right,. but what a strange thing to want to do, for no apparent reason, and I can't make any link to some chatbot and how this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working off some misconceptions. I take it you're expecting that line breaks in the text area will be reflected as line breaks in a paragraph if you insert it as the HTML of the paragraph. In HTML, all whitespace is collapsed into spaces, and line breaks in HTML source do not normally translate to breaks in HTML text flows. If you do want newlines to work in HTML, use a [`<pre></pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element instead. Otherwise you'll need to convert newlines to `<br>` elements.

There's also the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS style that can change the way that whitespace is rendered.